# Suggested command to eval "docker-machine env default" output fails on Cygwin

Tags: linux, bash, docker, cygwin

I am currently working on this: https://mozilla.github.io/ichnaea/install/devel.html#prerequisites and have been a bit stuck since they recommend working with Linux/Mac but I am limited to Windows. I tried getting their steps to work with Git Bash, Powershell, and Command Prompt but to no success. I am currently trying Cygwin to see if it would work however I am running into some issues. I currently run `docker-machine env default` and see the output:

```
 export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
 export DOCKER_HOST="..."
 export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="..."
 export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
 export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
 # Run this command to configure your shell:
 # eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env default)
```

When I attempt to run the command to configure the shell, `eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env default)`, I get an error saying: `-bash: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe: command not found`.

This is different than Git Bash, Powershell, and CMD since when I ran the respective commands on those shells there were no issues at all and it led me to successfully move on to the next steps. Is there any reason why I am getting this `command not found` error on Cygwin, and what should I do to fix it?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Converting paths to cygwin form takes some extra work -- looks like `docker-machine env default` doesn't do that work. See the `cygpath` tool, which you can use to do that conversion yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `cygpath` invocation to convert the executable path:

```
eval "$("$(cygpath -u "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe")" env default)"
```

Comment: Great that worked! Thanks for the explanation in the comments above.